# What is the most ideal way to pass a command line argument/option to be used in a script?

Tags: scripting

I need to write a script that takes user input at the command line and use it in the shell script. For example, create a script that will accept the command line options of `-u` (user) `-r` (number). I don't want to use Perl or something else and it should all be done in the same script. A second part to this question would be how to pass something similar to a different script but not a user name or a number of times the something would need to be created.

The script would then use that information to create a batch use to create the user bob x number of times for example if I typed

```
batch user -u bob -r 5
```

I would end up with user accounts bob1, bob2, bob3, bob4, bob5

I'm at a loss on the best way to do this.

Comment: So, are you asking about taking input from the command line, or about looping or about creating users? I'm not sure what the main issue is. There's probably a bunch of questions and resources on all of those here on SE and elsewhere, so perhaps you could look into some of them, see what you can get done by yourself and then come back when you've hit a wall?

Comment: "not perl or something else" is non-specific; do you care about what shell language you use, or not? What does the first script do with the -u and -r flags?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `getopts` to parse the command line. See `man bash` and search for `getopts` for details. Here is an example of how it could be used:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
usage="USAGE: ${0/*\/}  [-r <number>]  [-u <user>]"
while getopts ':r:u:' OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        r) thenumber="$OPTARG" ;;
        u) theuser="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) echo "$usage" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

echo "thenumber=${thenumber:-<unset>}"
echo "theuser=${theuser:-<unset>}"
exit 0
```